# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, valueerror

When I try to run this code, a `ValueError` appears alluding to the function `numRandom`. I though Python could pass a string representation of a int to an `int`.

```
import tkinter
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')

x = random.randint(1,300)
remainingTime = True
Attempts = 4

def numRamdom():
    global Attempts
    while Attempts > 0:
        numWritten = int(entryWriteNumber.get())
        if numWritten > x:
            lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a bigger number')
            Attempts = Attempts -1
        if numWritten < x:
            lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a smaller number')
            Attempts = Attempts -1
        if numWritten == x:
            lblClue.configure(text = 'Congratulations ;)')
            remainingTime = False
            return remainingTime, countdown(0)
        if Attempts == 0:
            remainingTime = False
            return remainingTime, countdown(0), Attempts, gameOver()

entryWriteNumber = tkinter.Entry(window)
entryWriteNumber.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

numRamdom()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do post the full error code.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/DESCARGAS/VisualCode/Ejercicios/AdivinadorInventor.py", line 73, in <module>
    numRamdom()
  File "d:/DESCARGAS/VisualCode/Ejercicios/AdivinadorInventor.py", line 28, in numRamdom
    numWritten = int(entryWriteNumber.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' `

Comment: Ive added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because when the code is ran, it directly calls `numRamdom()`, that is, initially the entry widgets are empty, and they run it with those empty entry widget and hence the error. So just assign a button and a command, like:

```
b = tkinter.Button(root,text='Click me',command=numRamdom)
b.grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Make sure to say this before the `mainloop()` after the `def numRamdom():`. The button just runs the function only when the button is clicked.

Or if you want button-less then try:

**METHOD-1:**

```
root.after(5000,numRamdom) #after 5 sec it will execute function
```

But keep in mind, if the user doesn't enter properly in 5 sec then some error would pop up.

**METHOD-2:**

```
def numRamdom(event):
......

entryWriteNumber.bind('<Return>',numRamdom)
```

This is so that, if you press enter key in the entry widget(after entering data) it will run the function.

Hope this helps, do let me know if any errors.

Cheers

Comment: But I want the user to be able to write from the beginning without clicking any button

Comment: @KIRA Then you can give them a time limit, like `root.after(5000,numRamdom)` which will give them 5 seconds to fill the entry box

Comment: @KIRA You could also use the `bind()` command to allow the user to press the return key for the function to call. 

`window.bind("<Return>",  numRamdom)`

Comment: @SanguineL it would require the window to have focus and not the entry widgets right?

Comment: @CoolCloud Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working example based on your code. Your problem was trying to convert the contents of the Entry before anything was inside of it. To fix this problem, you can add a button which calls the command `numRamdom()`

```
import tkinter
import random

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry('600x500')

x = random.randint(1,300)
remainingTime = True
Attempts = 4

def numRamdom():
    global Attempts, lblClue, x
    if Attempts > 0:
            numWritten = int(entryWriteNumber.get())
            if numWritten < x:
                lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a bigger number')
                Attempts = Attempts -1
            elif numWritten > x:
                lblClue.configure(text = 'Its a smaller number')
                Attempts = Attempts -1
            else:
                lblClue.configure(text = 'Congratulations ;)')
                remainingTime = False
                #return remainingTime, countdown(0)
            if Attempts == 0:
                remainingTime = False
                #return remainingTime, countdown(0), Attempts, gameOver()
    else:
        lblClue.configure(text = "You ran out of attempts!")

entryWriteNumber = tkinter.Entry(window)
entryWriteNumber.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10)

entryWriteButton = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Push me!", command = numRamdom)
entryWriteButton.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

lblClue = tkinter.Label(window)
lblClue.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


window.mainloop()
```

You'll still get an error if the value passed is not able to be converted into an integer, but that's easy to fix with an `if` statement.